# Wordpress - Gravityforms https:// is not a valid url

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I have a Wordpress based website that uses gravity forms. I have the gravity form loading in a jquery model window. My issue is the form seems to work except for after submission the form just stays on the screen and I see the below error in the console.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'href' property on 'Location': 'http://' is not a valid URL.
```

I am not sure why this error would occur and how http:// not be a valid url

Comment: `http://` all by itself is *not* a valid URL. If GravityForms is trying to redirect (and I think it is; the `Location:` header is used for redirection) and the URL it's trying to redirect to is simply `http://` and not, say, `http://example.com/redirect-here`, then yes, it would fail. Hopefully this helps; if not, you'll need to take this up with GravityForms' official support.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, `http://` is the protocol with which the thing requested is to be obtained.  The stuff after the `://` is the location at which the thing requested is located.  In order to be a valid **U**niform **R**esource **L**ocation, you need to provide the *location* at which the thing requested resides, not just the protocol used to obtain the thing.

So, if you want to use the **H**yper**T**ext **T**ransfer **P**rotocol to retrieve some hypertext (encodement in **H**yper**T** **M**arkup **L**anguage) located at `www.example.com/myfile.html`, your URL must be `http://www.example.com/myfile.html`.

With that said, I would first check the URL that you are sending with your form (if any).
If that doesn't work, you will have to trace the code (and your submission) to determine if a proper URL is being generated within the plugin to find the offending code or you are likely to continue getting that error.  Or, you could try [contacting Gravity Forms](https://www.gravityforms.com/support/) which is likely to be a better option because they are the ones who are responsible for writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. So I had the gravity form confirmation set to text but had no content in the wysiwyg. When I added content it seemed to fix the issues.
So it seems if in gravity forms you have text set as the confirmation but then don't put any text it tries to load a url by default.